# How do you plot two plots on the same graph in SPSS?

Tags: graph, spss

Is there a way to plot two (or more) separate graphs on one graph in SPSS?

Comment: Does anyone know?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want - [here is an example](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/side-by-side-charts-in-spss/).

Comment: Thank you! The link is helpful, but not exactly what I wanted. For example, I have two Kaplan Meier curves that are separated. I want to put the curves from both of them into one graph together with the same x and y axes. Is this possible in SPSS?